# AngularJs :: Share data between Views and parameters

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating an App with Ionic Framwork.
The Front is ok, and I made the view transitions using $stateProvider.

But I need to do the APP features and other functionalities. I have 2 major problems

1) Pass parameters through `href=""`

2) Execute some functions after the view transition e when the data is processed show the info on the new View.

Couldn't go further because I'm newbie at Angular and the other examples I searched were not specific.
That's what I got so far::

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as controller">
<ion-view title="View1"><ion-content>
   <a href="#/view2" ng-click="controller.test1">
      <button class="button-style">TEST 1</button>
   </a>
   <a href="#/view2" ng-click="controller.test2">
      <button class="button-style">TEST 2</button>
   </a>
</ion-content></ion-view>
...
```

**View2.HTML**

```
<ion-view title="View2"><ion-content>
   <input type="text" value="{{controller.parameter}}" />
</ion-content></ion-view>
```

**APP.JS**

```
app.config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('view2',{
            url:'/view2',
            templateUrl:'views/view2.html'
    })

...

app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    parameter = '';
    this.test1 = function(){
        alert('test1');
        parameter = 'One';
    };

    this.test2 = function(){
        alert('test2');
        parameter = 'Two';
    };
}]);
```

I've tried alot. But now it's just guessing :(

I didn't understand how Controllers and $scope works. I've saw some examples using factory and service, even the CodeSchool (awesome by the way) coudn't help me...

So, any good soul can bring some light here?

*Sorry about my misspelled english*

Comment: Are you looking to pass parameters via the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should be using the [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) attribute in your `<a>` tags (since you're using states, although using `href` works too), like this:

```
<a ui-sref="view2"></a>
```

And if you want to pass parameters, you have to configure your `state`'s `url` to accept parameters:

```
url: '/view2/:parameter'
```

To access `parameter` in your controller, you'll also need to inject `$stateParams` into your controller:

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $stateParams) {

});
```

And you access `parameter` via `$stateParams.parameter` like this:

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    alert($stateParams.parameter);
    $scope.parameter = $stateParams.parameter;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jia Jian, I understand your explanation but when I put on my code it didn't work...

I think I miss something implied on your code, but i don't know what...

Comment: Jia Jian, I dig i little more and found a friend that explaned to me. My problem was my own doubt.

I didn't know how to properly explain what I wanted. I showed him your code He said it was right, but wasn't what I was trying to do xD

I got your code as a Snippet for future problems :D :D

Thanks a lot!!

By the way, I was trying to SET data through a button on a controller on the next view....

I'm learning to use factory e properly use of MVC..... 
Sorry for the trouble and thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Do you want to post your solution as an answer in case someone else has that question? You can also accept your own answer.